# pick top rules only from stylelint-config-recommended

Tags: css, stylelint

I want to implement stylelint in my project. I came across "stylelint-config-recommended".
But after the first lint attempt, I got 100s of errors. I don't want to use all of the rules from the package "stylelint-config-recommended". Is there any way to just pick the top 10 or most commonly used rules for CSS linting from the package "stylelint-config-recommended"?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to determine the top 10 or most commonly used rules.

You can turn off the rules that are producing the most warnings and revisit them at a later date. The rules that remain turned on will stop new problems from being introduced into your code.

As an aside, the Stylelint team [recommends](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/get-started) extending the [`stylelint-config-standard`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stylelint-config-standard) which build on top of the `stylelint-config-recommended` package to help you write modern CSS that's consistent with the majority of the code examples found in the specifications.

For example, to extend the standard config and turn off the `no-descending-specificity` rule you can use:

```
{
  "extends": ["stylelint-config-standard"],
  "rules": {
    "no-descending-specificity": null
  }
}
```